# How to insert API data into Google Sheet/Doc

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

Is there a quick way to use web exposed APIs value in Google Sheet or Google Docs.

I've been researching a bit and I found Google Sheet API v4, but only applies to Google Sheet data or resources, not externals one in document.

EDIT: I don't want to develop a complete backend in Node nor Java (if possible), just a direct way to execute an script in Google Sheet/Doc, in order to get the data available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The available "direct way" of operating on Google Docs or Google Sheets that's available is through Apps Scripts. For Sheets, there's [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and for Google Docs there's [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/).

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know about theses links.